# Generic for unsafe: T[,] and T[,,] - C# 7.3+

Tags: c#, unsafe

I run c# 7.3 so please no comments like 'this will never work'

I have 2 Classes with a common interface:
Image2D and Image3D and the Common Interface Image

```
public interface IImage<T, S> where T : unmanaged {
  long Length { get; }
  S Data { get; }
  T GetMaxTypeValue();
  T GetMinTypeValue(); 
}

public abstract class I2D<T> : IImage<T, T[,]> where T : unmanaged {
    public int LengthX { get; }
    public int LengthY { get; }

    public T[,] Data { get; }
    ...
}


public abstract class I3D<T> : IImage<T, T[,,]> where T : unmanaged {
    public int LengthX { get; }
    public int LengthY { get; }
    public int LengthZ { get; }

    public T[,,] Data { get; }
    ....
}
```

What I am trying to do now: No matter if the input is of type I3D or I2D i need unsafe access on the Data array...

```
public static unsafe T Smth<T, S>(IImage<T, S> image) where T : unmanaged where S : unmanaged {
    var data = image.Data;

    fixed (T* pData = data) {
        do someting
    }
    return ...
}
```

This, of course, does not work: 'Can not convert initializer type S to type T*' which makes sense... But how Can I get the datatype of the arrays? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Arrays have too much syntax sugar in C# to easily see the issue.  The *unmanaged* constraint promises that a type is blittable, but arrays are not.  Only their content is.  The *fixed* keyword on an array type causes the C# compiler to emit a call to a special helper function to obtain the address of the first element, its name is T[].Address().  The number of arguments it takes depends on the rank of T.  So two big problems, the constraints are insufficient to help it know to use this helper function and how to call it correctly.  Lots of workarounds, but we can't see the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the trick here is instead of `S Data { get; }`, to have (either as `Data`, or as a different property): `ref T Data {get;}`.

Assuming you have underlying arrays, you should be able to use all the zeros to get this reference; so for the 2D case:

```
public ref T Data => ref arr[0, 0];
T[,] arr;
```

and for the 3D case:

```
public ref T Data => ref arr[0, 0, 0];
T[,,] arr;
```

Now you can use:

```
ref var data = ref image.Data;
fixed (T* pData = &data)
{

}
```

Although frankly I suspect you can also do everything you need *without* `unsafe` - especially via `MemoryMarshal` and `Unsafe` ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/))

Comment: Thanks, that helped, it is a little 'tinkered' in my opinion - but a valuable hint!